# WebdriverIO - Click element by index in async mode is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automation, webdriver-io

WebdriverIO no longer supports sync mode and I'm currently in the middle of transition to async. So far, everything was ok but I noticed that my methods for clicking/selecting elements by index stopped working e.g. this will work fine in sync mode:

```
get expandButtons()  {return $$(faqLocators.expandButton)};

clickOnExpandButtonByIndex(index: number) {
    const expandButton = this.expandButtons[index]
    expandButton.waitForExist()
    expandButton.click()
}
```

but the same method rewritten to async mode will throw an error so in my current implementation above method looks like this:

```
async clickOnExpandButtonByIndex(index: number) {
    const expandButton = await this.expandButtons[index]
    await expandButton.waitForExist()
    await expandButton.click()
}
```

Usage in test looks like this:

```
it('My test', async () => {
        await expect(faqPage.arrowDownIcon).toBeDisplayed();
        await faqPage.clickOnExpandButtonByIndex(0)
        await expect(faqPage.arrowUpIcon).toBeDisplayed();
    });
```

and above code throws following error:

```
 Cannot read property 'waitForExist' of undefined
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitForExist' of undefined
    at FAQPo.<anonymous> (/Users/badb/IdeaProjects/my-test-project/project/apps/retail-app-e2e/src/pages/FAQ/FAQ.po.ts:23:28)
     at step (/Users/badb/IdeaProjects/my-test-project/project/apps/retail-app-e2e/src/pages/FAQ/FAQ.po.ts:33:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/badb/IdeaProjects/my-test-project/project/apps/retail-app-e2e/src/pages/FAQ/FAQ.po.ts:14:53)
     at fulfilled (/Users/badb/IdeaProjects/my-test-project/project/apps/retail-app-e2e/src/pages/FAQ/FAQ.po.ts:5:58)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

 Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at FAQPo.<anonymous> (/Users/badb/IdeaProjects/my-test-project/project/apps/retail-app-e2e/src/pages/FAQ/FAQ.po.ts:23:28)
     at step (/Users/badb/IdeaProjects/my-test-project/project/apps/retail-app-e2e/src/pages/FAQ/FAQ.po.ts:33:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/badb/IdeaProjects/my-test-project/project/apps/retail-app-e2e/src/pages/FAQ/FAQ.po.ts:14:53)
     at fulfilled (/Users/badb/IdeaProjects/my-test-project/project/apps/retail-app-e2e/src/pages/FAQ/FAQ.po.ts:5:58)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I also have following warnings:

```
TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Element'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
```

I read in documentation that this is a common issue in async mode but suggested solutions are not working in my case. And I'm unable to click interact with multiple elements by index. Can someone explain me how to implement above methods in async mode? I referred to thi article https://webdriver.io/docs/sync-vs-async/

Comment: i am nto sure whay are you retruning element.click() , it doesn't return anything

Comment: So any ideas how can I change this? When I remove return at the end the method itself still don't work and the element is not clicked by index in async mode. Sorry for the silly questions but I'm new to JS/TS and async concept is sometimes hard to grasp for me. @PDHide

Comment: please add full stack trace whic hline causing the issue etc

Comment: @PDHide I added the error stack trace and some more details - hope this will help.

Comment: error means  await this.expandButtons[index] returns undefined , i

Comment: Ok, but I dont understand why this is not working in async while in sync it works as expected. Do you know what can I use instead of my solution in order to e.g. click on element by it's index?

Comment: expandButtons what is the code for this , can you add the intialization step for this variable

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong get, I updated the question but I use get expandButtons()  {return $$(faqLocators.expandButton)};

Basically I'm using wbedriverio $$() function to get all elements and then I try to access one element form the array by index eg. $$(faqLocators.expandButton)[0].click()

Answer (score 0):

```
   const expandButtons = await this.expandButtons()

    const expandButton = await this.expandButtons[index]
```

Expand button is a function not an array , so await for the function to give the elements array , then call index in it